# Cannot read from last remaining node in replica set

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3 node MongoDB (2.6.3) replica set and am testing various failure scenarios.

It was my understanding that if a majority of the replica nodes are not available then the replica set becomes read only. But what I am experiencing is if I shut down my 2 secondary nodes, the last remaining node (which was previously primary) becomes a secondary and I cannot even read from it.

From the docs:

> Users may configure read preference on a per-connection basis to
>   prefer that the read operations return on the secondary members. If
>   clients configure the read preference to permit secondary reads, read
>   operations can return from secondary members that have not replicated
>   more recent updates or operations. When reading from a secondary, a
>   query may return data that reflects a previous state.

It sounds like I can configure my client to allow reads from secondaries, but since it was the primary node that I left up, it should be up to date with all of the data. Does MongoDB make the last node secondary even if it is fully caught up with data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noted, once you've shut down the two secondaries, your primary steps down and becomes a secondary (it's a normal scenario once a primary looses connection to the majority of members).

The default read preference of a replica set is to read from primary, but since your former primary is not even primary anymore, as you have encountered , "I cannot even read from it."

You can change [read-preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) on a driver/database/collection and even operation basis.

> since it was the primary node that I left up, it should be up to date with all of the data. Does MongoDB make the last node secondary even if it is fully caught up with data?

As said, the primary becomes secondary as it steps down, nothing to do with the fact that it's up to date or not. It wouldn't read even because of the default read preference, if you will change your driver preference to secondary , nearest or so, you'll be able to continue reading even if a single node (former primary) remains.

Comment: Ok I see, but by specifying reads are allowed from secondaries I cannot then guarantee that data I read will be up to date right?

Comment: Also, is the node becoming a secondary how MongoDB accomplishes a read only database in the event of a loss of majority, or can you have a primary that is read only?

Comment: You are right. Note that you can use primary preferred read concern, which you can use it your special case. Also, you can have a read only database in any situation by specifying any read preference other than primary.